# mod_proxy_ajp error: renders html as text/plain, prompts user to "save as..."

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-proxy, ajp

We have an odd, intermittent error that occurs with mod_proxy_ajp, i.e. using apache as a front end to a tomcat server.

**The error**

- User clicks on a link browser prompts
  user to "save as...." (e.g. in
  Firefox "You have chosen top open
  thread.jsp which is a
  application/octet-stream"...What
  should firefox do with this file)
- User says "Huh?" and presses "Cancel"
- User clicks again on the same link
- Browser displays the page correctly

This error occurs intermittently, but unfortunately rarely on our test server and frequently on production.

In firefox's LiveHttpHeaders I see the following in the above usecase:

- first page download (i.e. click on link) is "text/plain"
- second download is "text/html"

I thought the problem may stem from ProxyPassReverse  (i.e. muddling up whether to use http or ajp), but all these proxypassreverse settings resulted in the same error:

- ProxyPassReverse /ajp://localhost:8080/
- ProxyPassReverse /pe http://localhost/pe
- ProxyPassReverse /pe http://forumstest.company.com/pe

Additionally, I've checked the apache error logs (set to debug) and see no warnings or errors...

** But it works with mod_proxy_http ?? **

It appears that switching to mod_proxy_http 'solves' the problem. Limited testing, I have not been able to recreate the problem in the test environment.

Because the problem is intermittent, I'm not 100% sure that mod_proxy_http "solves" the problem

**Environment**

- Apache 2.2 Windows
- Jboss 4.2.2 back end (tomcat 6)

**One other data point**

For better or worse, a servlet filter in tomcat gzips the html before sending it to apache. (which means extra work as apache must unzip before it performs ProxyPassReverse's "find and replace").  I don't know if "gzip" messes up.

**Questions**

- anyone seen this before?
- what tools help analyze the cause?

thanks

**Addendum 1: Here is the LiveHttpHeaders output**

*Browser Incorrectly sees html as "text/plain"*

```
http://forums.customer.com/pe/action/forums/displaythread?rootPostID=10842016&channelID=1&portalPageId=1002

GET http://forums.customer.com/pe/action/forums/displaythread?rootPostID=10842016&channelID=1&portalPageId=1002 HTTP/1.1
Host: forums.customer.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: __utma=156962862.829309431.1260304144.1297956514.1297958674.234; __utmz=156962862.1296760237.232.50.utmcsr=forumstest.customer.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/pe/action/forums/displaythread; s_vi=[CS]v1|258F5B88051D3FC3-40000105C056085F[CE]; inqVital=xd|0^sesMgr|{"sID":4,"lsts":1292598007}^incMgr|{"id":"755563420055418864","group":"CHAT","ltt":1292598006741,"sid":"755563549194447187","igds":"1290627502757","exempt":false}^inq|{"customerID":"755562378269271622"}^saleMgr|{"state":"UNSOLD","qDat":{},"sDat":{}}; inqState=sLnd|1^Lnd|{"c":4,"flt":1274728016,"lldt":17869990,"pgs":{"201198":{"c":1,"flt":1274728016,"lldt":0},"0":{"c":3,"flt":1274845009,"lldt":17752997}},"pq":["0","0","0","201198"],"fsld":1274728016697}; adv_search_results_page=10; ep_beta=1; visitorID=57307059; JSESSIONID=6jXLNdHRDjR9Th3B5gvTVkw1dZLn1zvhvKLR2r4GTLjylHJgjY3Q!683274050; __utmc=156962862; JSESSIONID=6jXLNdHRDjR9Th3B5gvTVkw1dZLn1zvhvKLR2r4GTLjylHJgjY3Q!683274050; TLTHID=5CCA50304DE99E28DB79A7B3267D4231; TLTSID=9DFCDE8045B374AAB752CC98A30E8311; AreCookiesEnabled=1; s_cc=true; SC_LINKS=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; __utmb=156962862.64.10.1297958674; memberexists=T; ev1=greywolf%20hdtv%20whmx
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Thu, 17 Feb 2011 17:38:42 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
X-Cache: MISS from samus.company.com
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from samus.company.com:3128
Via: 1.0 samus.company.com:3128 (squid/2.6.STABLE20)
Proxy-Connection: close
----------------------------------------------------------
```

*Browser Correctly sees html as "text/html"*

```
http://forums.customer.com/pe/action/forums/displaythread?rootPostID=10842016&channelID=1&portalPageId=1002

GET http://forums.customer.com/pe/action/forums/displaythread?rootPostID=10842016&channelID=1&portalPageId=1002 HTTP/1.1
Host: forums.customer.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: __utma=156962862.829309431.1260304144.1297956514.1297958674.234; __utmz=156962862.1296760237.232.50.utmcsr=forumstest.customer.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/pe/action/forums/displaythread; s_vi=[CS]v1|258F5B88051D3FC3-40000105C056085F[CE]; inqVital=xd|0^sesMgr|{"sID":4,"lsts":1292598007}^incMgr|{"id":"755563420055418864","group":"CHAT","ltt":1292598006741,"sid":"755563549194447187","igds":"1290627502757","exempt":false}^inq|{"customerID":"755562378269271622"}^saleMgr|{"state":"UNSOLD","qDat":{},"sDat":{}}; inqState=sLnd|1^Lnd|{"c":4,"flt":1274728016,"lldt":17869990,"pgs":{"201198":{"c":1,"flt":1274728016,"lldt":0},"0":{"c":3,"flt":1274845009,"lldt":17752997}},"pq":["0","0","0","201198"],"fsld":1274728016697}; adv_search_results_page=10; ep_beta=1; visitorID=57307059; JSESSIONID=6jXLNdHRDjR9Th3B5gvTVkw1dZLn1zvhvKLR2r4GTLjylHJgjY3Q!683274050; __utmc=156962862; JSESSIONID=6jXLNdHRDjR9Th3B5gvTVkw1dZLn1zvhvKLR2r4GTLjylHJgjY3Q!683274050; TLTHID=5CCA50304DE99E28DB79A7B3267D4231; TLTSID=9DFCDE8045B374AAB752CC98A30E8311; AreCookiesEnabled=1; s_cc=true; SC_LINKS=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; __utmb=156962862.64.10.1297958674; memberexists=T; ev1=greywolf%20hdtv%20whmx
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Thu, 17 Feb 2011 17:38:44 GMT
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.1.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_1_GA date=200707131605)/Tomcat-5.5
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 24739
X-Cache: MISS from samus.company.com
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from samus.company.com:3128
Via: 1.0 samus.company.com:3128 (squid/2.6.STABLE20)
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
----------------------------------------------------------
```

**Addendum 2: Additional Information**

The browser did receive the "gzipped" file. I had earlier clicked "save as..." when a few of these errors occurred. Gunzip successfully processed the files and converted them to html.

Comment: Did my answer ever help you out?

Comment: Facing the same problem in production. Could you please share the solution?

Answer (score 5):

Answer is here: [How to preserve the Content-Type header of a Tomcat HTTP response sent through an AJP connector to Apache using mod_proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399605/how-to-preserve-the-content-type-header-of-a-tomcat-http-response-sent-through-a)

set DefaultType to None in apache configuration.

```
# DefaultType: the default MIME type the server will use for a document
# if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
# If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
# a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
# or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
# keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
# text.
#
DefaultType None
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I could solve my problem. But mod_proxy_http itself looks unstable. So I used nginx as a proxy following the below page, and it works well so far.
https://komelin.com/articles/https-varnish

Comment: I think that this is a well maintained piece of code, so maybe you were experiencing problems because of misconfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

The first page download is of mime type "application/octet-stream". May be the zipped stream is being sent back to the browser? (You can confirm by saving the file and looking inside it.)

It would be really helpful to post the Live HTTP Header request / response traces for problematic and normal cases. If the content is same in both cases - the response HTML - may be forcing the mime type to be text/html (using ForceType directive) for that particular context can fix the issue.

If it turns out to be the case that gzipped content is being sent to the browser in the problematic case - then digging deeper would be necessary. Is this browser specific - only happens with Firefox or happens with all browsers?

Ok, based on the new information provided - looks like Squid is caching the problematic response and not sending the right headers back to the client. So the browsers are doing the right thing here - without the Content-Encoding and right Content-Type they cannot do much else.

Missing response headers for the problematic request :
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.1.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_1_GA date=200707131605)/Tomcat-5.5
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

X-Powered-By : It sounds like the problematic requests don't actually hit your JBoss server. Can you verify this by checking access logs? Is Squid caching the response and then sending it back as text/plain?

Reconfiguring Squid to not cache that particular URL should help - see http://www.lirmm.fr/doc/Doc/FAQ/FAQ-7.html section 7.8 for example (which is specific to Squid 2 but later versions should have similar capabilities.)

Comment: I've added the LiveHttpHeaders output to the original question.

Comment: i've confirmed that the 'save as...' file was indeed gzipped. I've  added this to the original question.

Comment: I shoudl also add that in our test environment, sometime the browser displayed directly the 'html'  (i.e. as if it were a text file). Other times in the test environment it prompted for "save as...." (which I presume would result in a .gzipped file)

Comment: As for browsers, IE had problems also (apparently worse). I wasn't able to test with IE due to DNS issues (wouldn't recognize changes to my hosts file) so don't have precise information.

Comment: Regarding SQUID and proxy, I confirmed this error occurs whether or not "behind the firewall"..i.e. connected via a proxy. I initially suspected it was a "firewall issue", but found it occurred when directly connected..

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a content-negotiation problem. Apache is guessing the content type using the "magic" byte and setting the content type incorrectly. That explains why it happens intermittently. Try disabling mod_negotiation and see what happens. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/content-negotiation.html for more info.

Comment: to clarify: when you say "disable mod_negotiation", do you mean a) commenting out mod_negotiation from httpd.conf *OR* b) updating another setting?  I didn't see any 'disable' option on the apache content-negotiation link

Comment: Commenting out will disable the module.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the following in your settings

```
ProxyPassReverse /ajp://localhost:8080/
```

But port 8080 is *not* ajp port. The default ajp port is **8009**. Could this be your problem?

Comment: Apache uses ProxyPassReverse to "find and replace" all header references, i.e. so redirects work.. I don't think it's related. It's easy to check by turning it off...

Answer (score 0):

It uses to be when apache *serves* secure content in a non secure channel.

Comment: Yes, in this case, with a http: URL the browser expects a clear text content, but if the delivered content is not, the browser treats them as octet-stream and so it prompts you to save it. You can check it easily by saving the file and then viewing it.

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely something wrong with your web application, not Apache. If your web app sends back the correct Content-Type, Apache will *gladly* forward it to the client. No content negotiation will be done in that case. If you do not return any Content-Type, Apache will almost surely substitute text/plain, which is not what you want.

Test your web app *without* Apache in the middle, make sure that it sends back the correct Content-Type.