# Content-Type header for 204 No Content response

Tags: apache, http

When my script respond with status `204 No Content` response, Apache adds `Content-Type` header automatically, even there is no content, just HTTP headers.

Is there a way to force Apache to not include `Content-Type` header with status `204` in `httpd.conf` or `.htaccess` configuration files, or even by any other way?

Comment: That's odd. What value does Apache set the header to?

Comment: @dland - In my case it is "text/plain; charset=utf-8", but I guess it depends on system configuration.

Comment: You can set the `DefaultType` to `None` in `httpd.conf`. (See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8398578/800579))